# remove the unmatched strings in R

Tags: r, tidyr, data-manipulation, stringr

I have a `data` as below and I would like to remove the values if they're not defined in `my.Housing` vector. many thanks in advance.

```
remove.this <- c("I do here some text that I want to remove from my dataset",
                 "var1", "var2")

my.Housing <- c("var1", "var2", "var3")

data <- data.frame(remove.this, my.Housing)

setdiff(remove.this,my.Housing)
```

Expected Answer

```
remove.this
N/A
var1
var2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `match`:

```r
data$my.Housing[match(data$remove.this, data$my.Housing)]
#[1] NA     "var1" "var2"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
my.Housing[remove.this %in% my.Housing]
```

Comment: This is not giving the expected output (NA missing, not the same length)

Comment: right.  So use this if you want the N/As eliminated. :)